# prop is being modified when data is modified?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Please see the following vue/nuxt component example:

```
<template>
    <my-component v-model="selected" :options="options" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        currentSelected: Array,
        options: Array
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selected: this.currentSelected
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When **'selected'** is updated by my-component, the prop is also being updated and is updating the data in the parent component.

Is this normal behaviour? If so (or not), why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal behavior. In Javascript, you can see objects and arrays as references.

That means that if you write the following code:

```
let obj = { foo: 'bar' }
let other = obj
other.foo = 'meh'
```

Then, `obj.foo` will be equal to `'meh'`.

If you want to clone your array into your component and avoid this behavior, you need to copy all the values from the array in props. To do this, you can use the following:

```
export default {
    props: {
        currentSelected: Array,
        options: Array
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selected: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentSelected))
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow your selected variable to lose all reference to your currentSelected prop.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on
> form input, textarea, and select elements. It automatically picks the
> correct way to update the element based on the input type.

from: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

This means that when selected is beeing updated, that also the prop is beeing updated, because the v-model directive creates a two-way data binding.

since currentSelected changes, the selected data property also changes and the two way binding of v-model will therefore also change the prop.